# How to add multiple user input char and int into arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem with my project in Java.

Here's the situation: the user will enter a character and integer of course code subj and units with a loop and restriction that indicates that when the total unit reaches "25" it will stop adding subj and course.

For example:

```
course code | subject   | units
------------+-----------+-------
GE 111      | education |     3
GE 112      | history   |     1
```

and so on..

After the user has entered the codes above, it will count all units and it will print to something thanks for the help. The code is too long, here is the most important part:

```
int[] a = new int[6];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("\nenter units");
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    a[j] = sc.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("your subjects are:\n : ");
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}

System.out.print("\nEnter course code:" + a);
code = br.readLine().charAt(0);
System.out.print("\nenter course description");
subj = br.readLine().charAt(0);
System.out.print("\nenter units");
units = br.readLine().charAt(0);
case 2: break;
case 3: break;
case 4: break;

}
}
```

Comment: Please point out what exactly the problem is. What errors do you get? What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make object of what you need to work with? Then you can have it so much easier. Make a class and constructor of whathewer you want to use as *entry* new Entry(data1,data2,data3) work with all of those. It will help you when you make your program more complex.

To sum up the array to get total units

```
int sum=0;
for(int i:yourArray){
sum+=i;
}
```

The problem is that you work with all of your data as individual pars try to make some connection between them. Make object and put some functions in. (sum units), (get desc) etc. - it will be easy for you then to precede.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this:

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Make one Course container list to store a set of courses
        List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>(); 

        //to store sum of units, intially 0
        int unitSum = 0;

        Course course = null;
        while(true){
            //make new course
            course = new Course();

            System.out.println("Enter course code:");
            course.setSubjectCode(sc.nextInt());//store course code

            System.out.println("Enter subject name:");
            course.setSubjectName(sc.next());//store subject name

            System.out.println("Enter units:");
            course.setUnits(sc.nextInt());//store units

            courses.add(course);//add Course to container

            //take sum of units
            unitSum += course.getUnits();
            if(unitSum>=25)//end loop if sum reached 25
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(courses);
        sc.close(); 
    }

}
```

Course.java

```
public class Course {

    private int subjectCode;
    private String subjectName;
    private int units;

    public Course() {       
    }

    public int getSubjectCode() {
        return subjectCode;
    }

    public void setSubjectCode(int subjectCode) {
        this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(int units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [subjectCode=" + subjectCode + ", subjectName="
                + subjectName + ", units=" + units + "]";
    }

}
```

this may help you..